# Is there a way to disconnect a Visual Studio 2008 Schema Compare from a database without closing the schema compare?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, database-schema

Let's say I want to (using Visual Studio) run a schema comparison between two databases, restore one of them from a backup, and run the schema comparison again. The schema comparison maintains a connection to the database, and SQL Server won't let me run the restore without removing all connections. Is there a way I can force the schema comparison to disconnect without closing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- Close all activities on the database (MSSMS right click on server > Activity monitor > close processes)
- Delete the database (check close all connections) then restore the database
- Change the connection to other database
- Save the schema compare > close it > restore > open schema compare

Comment: Changing the connection is probably the best way to go about it, and probably the only one I hadn't considered. I'll see if I can adapt it into my workflow.